# Bind Signal from two combined request with ReactiveCocoa

Tags: objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I'm new to ReactiveCocoa and I'm trying to create a Signal from two async requests.

That works fine when I try to catch next events inside my viewModel, but when I try to bind this signal in my view, it crashs.

My viewModel has these signals:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) RACSignal *combineSignal;
@property (nonatomic, strong) RACSignal *info;
@property (nonatomic, strong) RACSignal *permissions;
```

then, when I init this class

```
self.info = [self getUserInfo];
self.permissions = [self getUserPermissions];
self.combineSignal = [RACSignal combineLatest:@[self.info, self.permissions]
                                     reduce:^id(NSDictionary *infoDict, NSDictionary *permissionsDict){
                                         return @(1);
                                     }];
```

When I try to catch next events inside this block, it works: ex:

```
[self.combineSignal subscribeNext:^(id _) {
    NSLog(@"OK");
}];
```

But, when I try to catch next events inside my view, it crashs

View

```
self.viewModel = [[UserViewModel alloc] initWithServices:self.viewModelServices];

[self.viewModel.combineSignal subscribeNext:^(id _) {
    NSLog(@"OK");
}];
```

The crash log is:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ModelServicesImpl combineSignal]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff04243f400'
```

Comment: Can you add the entire `UesrViewModel`'s `-initWithServices:` initialiser?

Comment: let me explain in a simple way:


`self.someSignal = [RACObserve([SharedData shared], currentUser)  flattenMap:^RACStream *(RACSignal *signal) {
        return [self requestUserActiveLog];
    }];


[self.someSignal subscribeNext:^(id x) {
        NSLog(@"it works");
    }];`



someSignal only fires if I change [SharedData shared].currentUser before declare my Signal

Comment: sorry, my fault. currentUser was a getter and not a property. Now it works. And i'm pretty sure I don't need to use `flattenMap` because someSignal is the subscriber.